# Low Spark Streaming CPU utilization

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

In my Spark Streaming job, CPU is under utilized (only 5 -10 %).

It is fetching data from Kafka and sending to DynomoDB or thridparty endpoint.

Is there any recommendation for job that will better utilize the cpu resources, assuming that endpoint is not bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

The level of parallelism of Kafka depends on the number of partitions of the topic.

If the number of partitions in a topic is small, you will not be able to efficiently parallelize in a spark streaming cluster.

First, increase the number of partitions of the topic.

If you can not increase the partition of Kafka topic, increase the number of partitions by repartitioning after DStream.foreachRdd.

This will distribute the data across all the nodes and be more efficient.